# Name field is not returning anything on the second time through my while loop

Tags: java

This program is supposed to run through a while loop twice. The first time it runs through, it displays the name, occupation, age, salary and salary w/bonus. Yet, when the loop runs through for a second time, the name field is blank and the salary w/bonus is added onto the salary of the first employee. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Worker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name;
        int age;
        String occupation;
        double salary;
        double total = 10000;
        int count = 0;

        Employee employeeInfo = new Employee();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (count < 2) {

            //User Name
            System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
            name = keyboard.nextLine();
            employeeInfo.setEmployeeName(name);

            keyboard.nextLine();

            //User occupation 
            System.out.println("Enter your occupation: ");
            occupation = keyboard.nextLine();
            employeeInfo.setOccupation(occupation);

            //User age
            System.out.println("Enter your age: ");
            age = keyboard.nextInt();
            employeeInfo.setAge(age);

            //User salary
            System.out.println("Enter your salary: ");
            salary = keyboard.nextDouble();
            employeeInfo.setSalary(salary);
            total = total + salary;

            //Output information
            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Age: " + age);
            System.out.println("Occupation: " + occupation);
            System.out.println("Original Salary: " + salary);
            System.out.println("Salary with bonus: " + total);

            count++;
        }

        // employeeInfo.greetingMessage("");

    }

}





public class Employee {

    private String employeeName;// Employee Name
    private int age;// Employee Age
    private String occupation;// Employee job title
    private double salary;// Employee salary

    // Setters
    public void setEmployeeName(String name) {

        employeeName = name;// Initializes employee name

    }

    public void setAge(int num) {
        age = num;// Initializes employee age
    }

    public void setOccupation(String occu) {

        occupation = occu;// Initializes occupation
    }

    public void setSalary(double num2) {

        salary = num2;// Initializes salary
    }

    // Getters

    public String getEmployeeName() {

        return employeeName;
    }

    public int getAge() {

        return age;
    }

    public String getOccupation() {

        return occupation;
    }

    public double getSalary() {

        return salary;
    }


    public void greetingMessage(String greeting){
        System.out.println("Greetings " + getEmployeeName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with Scanner. You shouldn't call `nextLine` after `nextInt` - I read that [here](http://java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html).  You need to make a second scanner and use it to capture the numbers, like so:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner key2 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

When you want a string use the first one and for a number use the second:

```
name = keyboard.nextLine();
age = key2.nextInt();
```

Also, instantiate your Employee object inside the while loop or it will be overwritten with each iteration.

```
while (count < 2) {
  employeeInfo = new Employee();
```

Finally, remove the 2nd `nextLine` after you get the name but before you get the occupation.

Answer (score 0):

You should move this line within the loop so a new employee object is created in each iteration

```
Employee employeeInfo = new Employee();
```

Also there is an extra `keyboard.nextLine();` after you read the name from keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your Employee oject at the beginning of your while loop:

```
while(count < 2)
{
    Employee employeeInfo = new Employee();
    //...rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: He never does anything with the `employeeInfo` instance anyway - that is not the problem.